# Unable to connect to docker container of mysql-server using local mySQL Workbench and mySQL workbench container both

Tags: mysql, docker, workbench

I have `mysql-server container` and `mySQL workbench` running on `docker` as follows:

[image]

I've tried connecting my local `mySQL Workbench`  and `Workbench conatainer` both to connect to docker container `mysql-server`. I have done with the access grant part to the root user too. Still, `mySQL workbench` shows the following:

[image]
[image: "failed to connect to mysql at 127.0.0.1"]

Whereas I can easily connect `mysql-server container` with `mysql-client` using terminal and it's working perfectly fine:

[image]